# Find the sum of the series $1-2^2+5-4^2+9-6^2....+(2n-3)-n^2$

Tags: sequences-and-series

We can take the $T_n$ term to be $2n-3-n^2$

One problem here is that if you put 1 in $T_n$, you don’t get the respective first two terms in the given series. So there are actually $n-1$ terms, rather than $n$ terms.

So $$\sum 2k-3-k^2$$
$$=\frac{(2)(k)(k+1)}{2}-3k-\frac{(k)(k+1)(2k+1)}{6}$$

However, plugging in $n-1$ doesn’t give the right answer, which is $\frac{-n}{6}(n^2+5)$

I think the problem is in the $T_n$ term I have chosen, but I can’t seem to pinpoint it

Comment: $5-4^2$ is not $2\cdot 2-3-2^2$ either, and $9-6^2$ is not $2\cdot 3-3-3^2$. So either the person who wrote $2n-3-n^2$ is wrong or the person who wrote the first terms is.

Comment: $2n-3$ has these values: $-1,1,3,5,...$ so that guess is wrong.

Comment: There's something really weird going on. I don't see how
$$
1-2^2 + 5 - 4^2 + 9 - 6^2 \ldots
$$
is related to $2n-3-n^2$. The squared terms are only $2,4$ and $6$ so definitely we're skipping over some terms. I guess you mean to group the terms like this: 
$$
(1-2^2) + (5 - 4^2) + (9 - 6^2) + \ldots
$$
Then please revise your general term. I think Henry got the point, there ...

Comment: Is your sum not $4n-3-n^2$?

Comment: $T_2=-3=1-2^2$ and $T_4=-11=5-4^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative approach:

Noting that $5=3^3-2^2$, $9=5^2-4^2$ etc. we can re-write the series as

$1^2 - 2^2 + (3^2-2^2) - 4^2 + (5^2-4^2) - 6^2 + (7^2-6^2) + \dots \\
= 1^2 + 2^2 + (3^2 -3.2^2) + 4^2 + (5^2-3.4^2) + 6^2 + (7^2 - 3.6^2) + \dots$

and so the sum of $2n+1$ terms is

$\displaystyle \sum_{m=1}^{2n+1} m^2 - 3\sum_{m=1}^{n} (2m)^2 \\
\displaystyle =\sum_{m=1}^{2n+1} m^2 - 12\sum_{m=1}^{n} m^2 \\
\displaystyle = \frac{(2n+1)(2n+2)(4n+3)}{6} - \frac{12n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}\\
\displaystyle = \frac{(2n+1)(2n+2)}{6} ( (4n+3) - 6n)
\displaystyle = \frac{-(2n+1)(2n+2)((2n+1)-4)}{6}$

So the sum of $k$ terms where $k$ is odd is

$\displaystyle\frac{-k(k+1)(k-4)}{6} = \frac{-k(k^2-3k-4)}{6}$

and if $k$ is even we take the sum of $k-1$ terms and subtract $k^2$ to get

$\displaystyle\frac{-k(k-1)(k-5)}{6} - k^2 = \frac{-k(k^2+5)}{6}$

So the given answer is correct for an even number of terms.

Comment: Why are there $2n+1$ terms?

Comment: @Aditya Because in the first part I wanted to find the sum of $k$ terms when $k$ is odd, and the simplest way to express this restriction is to say $k=2n+1$ where $n$ is an integer. Then when we have an expression for the sum in terms of $n$, we can convert back to an expression in $k$ using $k=2n+1$.

Answer (score 2):

You can write: $$S=2\sum_{i=1}^{n}i-\sum_{i=1}^{n}3-\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^2$$
This is very simple, in fact: $$S=2\cdot\frac{n}{2}(n+1)-3n-\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}=\frac{6n^2+6n-18n-2n^3-n^2-2n^2-n}{6}=\frac{-2n^3+3n^2-13n}{6}=-\frac{1}{3}n^3+\frac{1}{2}n^2-\frac{13}{6}n$$

Comment: But there is no $n^2$ term in the answer.

Comment: @Aditya: yes, I know, but if you try ckecking also with sum instruments online, my formula is correct.

Comment: But is the given answer wrong, since the way Henry did it in the another answer is the way given in the book

Comment: @Aditya: see this page where you can find the closed form of the sum https://www.symbolab.com/solver/series-calculator/%5Csum_%7Bi%3D1%7D%5E%7Bn-1%7D%202i-3-i%5E%7B2%7D and this page where there is the simplification of the result https://www.symbolab.com/solver/simplify-calculator/simplify%20n%5E%7B2%7D-4n%2B3-%5Cfrac%7Bn%5Cleft(n-1%5Cright)%5Cleft(2n-1%5Cright)%7D%7B6%7D

Answer (score 1):

Try using something like $$T_m=4m-3 -4m^2$$

The sum of m such terms is $$4\frac{m(m+1)/2}2−3m−4\frac{m(m+1)(2m+1)}6=−\frac13(4m^3+5m)$$

Alternatively, take your $T_n=2n-3 -n^2$ to apply when $n$ is even

Comment: I could group them to be $(1+5+9...)-4(1^2+-2^2-3^2....)$, but that would require knowing the total number of terms. There is no indication on whether the number of terms are odd or even.

Comment: Okay, your approach is correct. Can you explain how you got $4m-3-4r^2$?

Comment: $1,5,9,\ldots$ keeps increasing by $4$ so is $4\times 1-3,4\times 2-3, 4\times 3-3, \ldots$ while $2^2,4^2,6^2\dots = 4\times 1^2,4\times 2^2, 4\times 3^2, \ldots$

Comment: Are the numbers of terms for both the series the same? That would require them to be even.